# How to run my app even after iPhone screen locks?

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I want my app (LaunchDaemon) to keep running even if user locks the iPhone. My LaunchDaemon simply check a file and if some condition is true, it displays an Alert to the User. Its working great when iPhone is on Home Screen, but it is not working when user Locks the Screen.

I want something Similar to Alarm app of iPhone which will show an Alert even if the iPhone screen is Locked.

Any suggestions on how to do this? BTW i am developing for JB iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright i have solved this problem too.

Here is a very good tutorial on how to prevent deep sleep of iPhone.

[Prevent iPhone Deep Sleep](http://marcopeluso.com/2009/08/23/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping/)

It took me quite sometime to made this work, as NSRunLoop was not running for me automatically.

Hope this will help someone else also.

Best of Luck !!!

Comment: this will end up in rejection.

Comment: Link is dead for me.

Answer (score 1):

OS powers down the device and suspends your app after about 30 seconds after screen is locked. However,
if your app is playing a sound OS will not do that. Hence what you need to do is play a silent sound in a loop.

Comment: Playing silent sound in a loop will drain the battery right? Is it safe to do this?

Comment: @raziiq - it will but only playing sound isn't that big of a deal. as far as I remember playing it (plus some other stuff) for 10hours drains <20% of iphone's (I might be wrong, I did the tests quite long time ago but it's not like you end up with 10% lest after 12 hours or something)